# Create a multi.sj shiny widget with country flags in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

Im trying to create a multi.js shiny widget like this [here](http://shinyapps.dreamrs.fr/shinyWidgets/). But I miss the `flags` object. Anyone knows where can I find and load it?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
 countries<-c("Belgium","Greece","Brazil")

ui <- fluidPage(
  multiInput(
    inputId = "Id010",
    label = "Countries :", 
    choices = NULL,
    choiceNames = lapply(seq_along(countries), 
                         function(i) tagList(tags$img(src = flags[i],
                                                      width = 20, 
                                                      height = 15), countries[i])),
    choiceValues = countries
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Base on chrome's devtools, it seems the images are pulled from here: https://cdn.rawgit.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/master/flags/4x3/de.svg

Comment: thanks and how can I load and use them?

Comment: you can define a character that contains the url and pass them to the `src` parameter of `tags$img`

Comment: thanks I will accept this if you put is an answer to original Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on chrome's devtools, it seems the images in the shinyWidgets gallery are pulled from urls like this one here: https://cdn.rawgit.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/master/flags/4x3/de.svg.

If you want to include this into the input widget, you'll need to define a character vector that holds the corresponding urls

```r
countries <- c('de', 'at', 'br')

img_urls <- paste0(
  'https://cdn.rawgit.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/master/flags/4x3/',
  countries, '.svg'
)

input_widget <- multiInput(
  inputId = "Id010",
  label = "Countries :", 
  choices = NULL,
  choiceNames = lapply(
    seq_along(countries), 
    function(i) {
      tagList(
        tags$img(src = img_urls[i], width = 20, height = 15), 
        countries[i]
      )
    }
  ),
  choiceValues = countries
)
```

Then you can place the input widget anywhere in you UI

```r
shinyApp(fluidPage(input_widget), function(...) {})
```

Comment: Could you take a look at this shiny issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71023022/create-a-dynamic-table-on-shiny-app-based-on-shiny-widget-and-row-selection-of-a